# How to add multiple layers to a site without affecting the content?

Tags: html, css

I What is the best way to add multiple layers with the help of z-index to a site without affecting any of the existing content? One layer would be positioned absolute, the second for example relative, 3rd would be fixed and so on.

I don't know, if I'm making a mistake over again, but I've tried this more than once and it works good with two or three layers. With more (e.g. 10 layers), it starts affecting the position of some elements, so I adapt their position, but I think, that that's only a visual solution.

Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. Consider setting up a demonstration on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the layers in the same manner as the rest, so, yes you can create more layers on top of one another without affecting the positioning. The content of each layer should be the same size, so as not to push the *height* or *width*. Btw, position them all as **absolute** and you are good to go. See multiple layers in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/BcAWC/

The sample code:

CSS:

```
div { width: 300px; height: 300px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid black;  position: absolute; }
div#layer1 { background-color: red; }
div#layer2 { background-color: green; }
div#layer3 { background-color: blue; }
div#layer4 { background-color: red; }
div#layer5 { background-color: green; }
div#layer6 { background-color: blue; }
div#layer7 { background-color: red; }
div#layer8 { background-color: green; }
div#layer9 { background-color: blue; }
div#layer10 { background-color: red; }

p { color: white; font-size: 50px; margin-top: 120px; }
.movetotop { z-index: 10; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="layer1" class="">
    <p>Layer 1</p>
</div>
<div id="layer2" class="">
    <p>Layer 2</p>
</div>
<div id="layer3" class="">
    <p>Layer 3</p>
</div>
<div id="layer4" class="">
    <p>Layer 4</p>
</div>
<div id="layer5" class="">
    <p>Layer 5</p>
</div>
<div id="layer6" class="">
    <p>Layer 6</p>
</div>
<div id="layer7" class="">
    <p>Layer 7</p>
</div>
<div id="layer8" class="movetotop">
    <p>Layer 8</p>
</div>
<div id="layer9" class="">
    <p>Layer 9</p>
</div>
<div id="layer10" class="">
    <p>Layer 10</p>
</div>
```

​--

Move the class "**movetotop**" across each layer to see the movement of layers going on top of the other.

Comment: What if I need to use a relative position or a different width/height?

Comment: Using a relative position will break the normal positioning and will resume _relative_ to the previous element in your code. You can use a relative position as a wrapper, to wrap a group of absolutely positioned layers altogether [but not mix them like spaghetti and meatballs]. Same goes when the width and height are being manipulated, the rest of the content [below or on either side] will be pushed away.

Comment: I understand now why I had those problems. Thank you.